Are there any statistics of parachute deployment from gliders?
Thinking about this question, I realised that I've only worn a parachute inside an aircraft when flying sailplanes.  I wondered how often and how successful are glider bail-outs- have the numbers been collected anywhere?
I'm mainly asking about sailplanes that the pilot (and passenger) need to climb out of,  rather than paragliders and hang gliders - reserves seem to be deployed fairly frequently in those cases.

You should be able to collect some data by sampling NTSB events for some period, say a decade's worth, of glider mid airs and structural failures.
